# Today's date in a disabled input box

Tags: html, asp.net, jsp, date

I would like to ask how to display today's date into a disabled input date box?

date.html:

```
<input id="today" type="date" disabled>
```

calender.jsp:

```
<script>document.getElementById('today').value = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'); </script>
```

Comment: You can use onLoad instead of  onFocus.

Comment: @Alexey Subach Thank you for your editing. I did learn something.

Comment: @ChetanPanchal <input onLoad="meizzToday()" size="10" name="Date_Created" maxlength="10" disabled>

Comment: @ jenn you can set the today's date on this disabled field on page load.Not on Focus because you can't focus on disabled fields.

Comment: @Chetan Panchal 
<input id="today" type="date" disabled>
<script>document.getElementById('today').value = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
</script>

Comment: @ jenn yes this way you can set date.

Comment: @Chetan Panchal But I still fail to display today's date

Comment: @ jenn you need to set document.ready function and in this you can call the function to set the date on disabled date.

Comment: @ jenn OR you can set the date on page load and then after you can disabled this field.

Comment: @Chetan Panchal   $(document).ready( function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var today = now.getDate()  + '/' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + now.getFullYear();
    alert(today);
    $('#datePicker').val(today);
});​

Comment: $(document).ready( function() { 
 var now = new Date(); 
 var today = now.getDate() + '/' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + now.getFullYear();
  alert(today); 
 $('#datePicker').val(today);
 $('#datePicker').attr('disabled');  
});​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work...

```js
var date = document.getElementById('today');

var day = new Date();
var thisDate = day.getDate();
var thisMonth = day.getMonth()+1;
var thisYear = day.getFullYear();

if(thisDate<10){
    thisDate='0'+thisDate;
} 
if(thisMonth<10){
    thisMonth='0'+thisMonth;
} 

date.value = thisYear+'/'+thisDate+'/'+thisMonth;
```

```html
<input id="today" disabled value="21/03/2017">
```

Comment: It works for me. Could you please explain briefly on your code? Thank you and appreciate for your help.

Comment: Could u please explain the following?           if(thisDate<10){
    thisDate='0'+thisDate;
} 
if(thisMonth<10){
    thisMonth='0'+thisMonth;
}

Comment: Thanks Jenn...!! I just trying to format the date by adding 0 to the default value..

Comment: Why is less than value of 10?

Comment: if the date or month value less than 10 it will add 0 to the default value.... i hope you got it... thanks

Comment: because i am trying to format ... the date from : 2017/3/21 to 2017/03/21

Comment: Since there is no effect on it. Why can't we just remove this  if(thisDate<10){ thisDate='0'+thisDate; } if(thisMonth<10){ thisMonth='0'+thisMonth; }  ?

Comment: assume if the default date value is : 2017/2/2 it will covert format that to 2017/02/02

Comment: Okay Got it! Can't it be display as 2017/3/21 instead of 2017/03/21 ?

Comment: you can.. just remove the if condition... it is just for format only... thanks

Comment: I've tried to remove it.. But today's date didnt display anymore